# Split string in c#, empty space also considered as string how to discard empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a text box where I enter the input as

```
"Two; abc@kk.com;"

string[] result = txt_to.Text.Split(';');
```

so what happens here is the result takes three strings.
1. two
2. abc@kk.com
3. "" (empty space) since there is a ; after the email it considers that as a string how can I discard the 3rd string that it takes. It happens when I enter the email and a semicolon and press the space bar it throws a error. If it is just space after the semicolon the split should discard it how to do that

Answer (score 12):

I'm gathering you want to split the string into a number of strings, but exclude any "empty" strings (those consisting only of whitespace)? [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) ought to help you out...

```
string[] result = txt_to.Text.Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var arr = mystring.Split(new string[]{";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Does RemoveEmptyEntries also remove a space? I thought it was just for removing String.Empty... Haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 3):

Pass [StringSplitOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) parameter

```
var result = yourString.Split(new string[] {";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the same method, adding `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like it would make sense to discard empty strings from the result anyway, not only at the end. If this is the case, you could use

```
char[] separators = new char[]{';'};
string[] result = txt_to.Text.Split(separators , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s=txt_to.Text;
s = s.Replace(" ", "");
string[] result = s.Split(';');
```